# FormControl not updating state pristine/dirty or value after making changes to form

Tags: angular, typescript, cron, angular-reactive-forms, angular-directive

Angular newbie here

### The Problem

I am using [this library to create a crontab expression generator](https://github.com/claudiuconstantin/cron-editor). The directive has been imported into a page with another existing form. I was able to run the custom directive just fine, and it works perfectly. On clicking the options and inputs, it is generating the correct cron tab expression. The final expression is displayed on a single `<b></b>` element.

I am unable to get the final expression after all the changes. Whenever I output the form, I get the default values which I set when creating the directive. In the DOM also, I am able to see that the expression is sitting right there. I am having trouble getting that final expression.

[image: dom works fine]

As you can see here, the expression is correct, but I am not able to get to it.

### Code

```
        this.cronForm = new FormControl(this.cronExpression);
        this.scheduleForm = new FormGroup({
            startDate: new FormControl({value: ''}),
            endDate: new FormControl({value: ''}),
        });
```

There are two forms, and the scheduleForm works just fine, and whenever I make any change, the values reflect and also the state changes. The cronForm, however, when logging the values and state in the console, it shows the same default values always, and the state stays pristine:

[image: other form works fine]

This is my component.ts file:

```
#imports and stuff
export class ScheduleComponent implements OnInit {
    public cronExpression = '55 17 ? * MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI';
    cronForm: FormControl;
    scheduleForm: FormGroup;

    constructor() {
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {

        this.cronForm = new FormControl(this.cronExpression);
        this.scheduleForm = new FormGroup({
            startDate: new FormControl({value: ''}),
            endDate: new FormControl({value: ''}),
        });
    }


    save() {
        let requestPayload: any = {}
        requestPayload.notification = {
            startDate: this.scheduleForm.controls.startDate.value,
            endDate: this.scheduleForm.controls.endDate.value,
        }
        console.log(this.scheduleForm);
        console.log(this.cronForm);
    }
}
```

Here is my template:

```
    <form [formGroup]="scheduleForm">
        <div class="panel base-margin-top">
            <div drawer-content class="col-6">

                <div class="row base-margin-top">

                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group base-margin-bottom">
                            <div class="form-group__text">
                                <cng-form-field>
                                    <input cngInput formControlName="startDate" type="date"/>
                                    <label>Start Date</label>
                                </cng-form-field>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group base-margin-bottom">
                            <div class="form-group__text">
                                <cng-form-field>
                                    <input cngInput formControlName="endDate" type="date"/>
                                    <label>End Date</label>
                                </cng-form-field>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-10 cron-tab-container">
                <cron-editor [(cron)]="cronExpression" [disabled]="isCronDisabled" [(options)]="cronOptions">
                    Cron here...
                </cron-editor>

                <div class="row alert alert-info" style="text-align:center">
                    <h3>
                        <b>{{cronExpression}}</b>
                    </h3>
                    <hr/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6 row base-margin-top flex flex-right">
            <button class="btn btn--link">Cancel</button>
            <button (click)="save()" class="btn btn--primary" [disabled]="!scheduleForm.valid">
                <span>Send</span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Can you show us your template? Reactive forms require that you bind the FormControls and FormGroups to the template, without that Angular won't know to which HTML element does it need to bind too.

Comment: please include your template

Comment: I don't see the `cronForm` property applied to the template. You assign it once on the `ngOnInit` hook and that is it. Why don't you use the `cronExpression` instead?

Comment: I am sorry but I don't understand, where should I use cronExpression ? Also, if `cronForm` does not exist in the template, how come I get the console for `cronForm`? Do you mean to say that form never actually rendered on the html ? Where should I include the 'cronForm' ? This is the library I am using for this cron-tab generation: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron-editor

Comment: The `scheduleForm` **is** bound to the template but the `cronForm` **is not**. But from what I understand, you just want the final cron expression, correct? So in the `save` method, you can print to the console the value of `this.cronExpression` instead of the `this.cronForm` and see if that print out the value that you want, then you can do whatever you want with it.

Comment: @DavidFontes Thanks, that worked!!

Comment: Glad it helped :) I will write an answer for the sake of it, accept it if you want :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `scheduleForm` **is** bound to the template but the `cronForm` **is not**. But from what I understand, you just want the final cron expression, correct? So in the `save` method, you can print to the console the value of `this.cronExpression` instead of the `this.cronForm` and see if that print out the value that you want, then you can do whatever you want with it.

```
export class ScheduleComponent implements OnInit {
    public cronExpression = '55 17 ? * MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI';
    cronForm: FormControl;
    scheduleForm: FormGroup;

    constructor() { ... }

    ngOnInit(): void { ... }

    save() {
        let requestPayload: any = {}
        requestPayload.notification = {
            startDate: this.scheduleForm.controls.startDate.value,
            endDate: this.scheduleForm.controls.endDate.value,
        };
        console.log(this.scheduleForm);
        console.log(this.cronForm);        // <-- Not being used
        console.log(this.cronExpression);  // <-- This one is!
    }
}
```

Comment: It's weird the `cronForm` is not being used the way I thought it was being used. Nevertheless, I got what I wanted.

Comment: Just some more information. You were not using the `cronForm`, to do so, you would have to do the same as you did to the `scheduleForm`, which is bind it to template by using the `formControlName` directive, but that would only work for valid input like elements. In order for the element `cron-editor` to act like an input, the authors of the package should have used the [Angular control value accessor](https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor), which I don't know if they have, so your current implementation looks like is the best approach.